# Incorrect drawing of box

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I have a problem with drawing a box shape (it is very long)

[image: Long box]

Code to create the matrix (where width and height are the size of the window):

```
GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
                GL.DepthMask(true);
                GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Lequal);

                float aspect = (float)width / (float)height;

                matrix = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(0, 0, -100) * // 100 > 51 
                                 Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveOffCenter(-aspect, aspect, 1, -1, 1, 1000);
```

Code to draw Box:

```
public void Box(double w, double h, double d)
    {
        float x1 = (float)-w / 2f; float x2 = (float)w / 2f;
        float y1 = (float)-h / 2f; float y2 = (float)h / 2f;
        float z1 = (float)-d / 2f; float z2 = (float)d / 2f;

        var vertbuffer = new Vector3[]
        {
            // front
            new Vector3(x1, y1, z1),
            new Vector3(x2, y1, z1),
            new Vector3(x2, y2, z1),
            new Vector3(x1, y2, z1),

            // right
            new Vector3(x2, y1, z1),
            new Vector3(x2, y1, z2),
            new Vector3(x2, y2, z2),
            new Vector3(x2, y2, z1),

            // back
            new Vector3(x2, y1, z2),
            new Vector3(x1, y1, z2),
            new Vector3(x1, y2, z2),
            new Vector3(x2, y2, z2),

            // left
            new Vector3(x1, y1, z2),
            new Vector3(x1, y1, z1),
            new Vector3(x1, y2, z1),
            new Vector3(x1, y2, z2),

            // top
            new Vector3(x1, y1, z2),
            new Vector3(x2, y1, z2),
            new Vector3(x2, y1, z1),
            new Vector3(x1, y1, z1),

            // bottom
            new Vector3(x1, y2, z1),
            new Vector3(x2, y2, z1),
            new Vector3(x2, y2, z2),
            new Vector3(x1, y2, z2),
        };

        GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
        GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.NormalArray);

        GL.VertexPointer(3, VertexPointerType.Float, Vector3.SizeInBytes, vertbuffer);
        GL.NormalPointer(NormalPointerType.Float, Vector3.SizeInBytes, normalBuffer);

        GL.Color4(fillColor);
        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Quads, 0, vertbuffer.Length);

        GL.Color4(strokeColor);
        GL.LineWidth((float)strokeWeight);

        for (int i = 0; i < vertbuffer.Length / 4; i++)
        {
            GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.LineLoop, i * 4, 4);
        }
    }
```

it does look like the front quad isnt draw:

[image]

I have tried to reduce the depthFar parameter of the `Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveOffCenter` but this doesn't work.

Edit: I've updated the code.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work, it has the same result

Comment: Try `matrix = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(0, 0, -5) * Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveOffCenter(width/-2f/height, width/2f/height, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 1000);`

Comment: the same result unfortunately i have updated the question with more info. thank you for helping ;)

Comment: What are the actual values for `w`, `h` and `d`. Is the [Depth test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) enabled?

Comment: depth test is enabled and the values of w, h and d are 100

Comment: Why have you updated the code? What has changed in behavior?

Comment: Man the cannot be. When you change the matrix then the scene cannot look the same. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: in one of the images there are black lines i wanted to show how i did that and i've added the code i use for the depth testing.

Comment: the question stays the same but i updated the code because perhapse the new code could have broken it more. perhapse the depth testing is incorrect

Comment: How do you set the matrix? Do you have a shader program?

Comment: i use the default shader program. this code is run everytime in draw: GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
    GL.LoadMatrix(ref matrix);

Comment: Actually I cannot reproduce the issue. The updated code works fine for me. Doe you set the projection matrix? (`GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection)`)

Comment: after alot of debuffing and testing today i've found the bug: i forgot to set the modelview matrix. thank you so much for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the geometry which is not in between the near and the far plane is clipped.

[image]

The size of your cube is 100, 100, 100. The distance to the near plane is 1 and the distance to the far plane is 1000.
Hence, the distance between the camera and the center of the cube must be at least 51 (d/2 + near = 100/2 +1), otherwise the front of the cube will be cut off by the close plane of the [Viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum).

The OpenGL coordinate system is a [right handed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) system. The x axis points to the right and the y axis points up. The z axis is computed by the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of x axis and y axis and points out of the view. Therefore the geometry must be shifted in the negative z direction.

I recommend to use the following projection and translation for a cube with the size 100x100x100:

```cs
float aspect = (float)width/(float)height;
matrix = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(0, 0, -100) * // 100 > 51
    Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveOffCenter(-aspect, aspect, 1, -1, 1, 1000);
```

Comment: after trying your code it results in the same result. I've updated the code and tried different values but this doesn't work.